# How to output a single [Int] from this function?

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char

type Games = (String, String, Int)

test :: [Games]
test =
    [
    ("Minecraft","mojang",100),
    ("GTA V","rockstar",500),
    ("Portal","valve",200),
    ("GTA IV","rockstar",100)
    ]

-- give the total number of sales for a studio
studioSales :: String -> [Games] -> [Int]
studioSales studioName [] = []
studioSales studioName ((name,studio,quantitySold):xs)
   | studioName == studio = quantitySold: studioSales studioName xs 
   | otherwise = studioSales studioName xs
```

When the function " studioSales "rockstar" test " is called the value returned is "[500,100]".

How can I modify this so when " studioSales "rockstar" test " is called, the value returned is "[600]", where two of the Int's are added up.

Also how can i add up all the sales? so a function that would return all the integers added up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to do a fold on the output of the function to sum up the results ,like so:

```
foldl (+) 0 $ studioSales "rockstar" test
```

Using the above idea, we can change the function itself to return a single `Int` value by adding the elements of the list of `Int`s that you return at the moment:

```
sumByStudio:: String -> [Games] -> Int
sumByStudio studioName [] = 0
sumByStudio studioName xs = foldl (\x acc -> if fst acc == studioName then x + snd acc else x) 0 $ map getStudioAndCount xs

getStudioAndCount :: Games -> (String, Int)
getStudioAndCount  (x,y,z) = (y,z)
```

Note the use of a helper function to get a tuple of the 2 elements that actually matter. But this still looks ugly, and can be made more concise.

Now that we have the basic idea of folding to get the sum,we change it, first by using `filter` to get all records for the chosen studio, and then using `foldr`:

```
sumByStudio:: String -> [Games] -> Int
sumByStudio3 studioName [] = 0
sumByStudio3 studioName xs = foldr(\(_,_,z) acc -> z + acc) 0 $ filter (\(_,y,_) -> y == studioName) xs
```

Note that using pattern matching within the lambdas eliminates the need for a helper function like we used in the example with `foldl`.

Finally, since all the above essentially return a value that represents a sum, it would probably be a good idea to have the return type be `Int` instead of an `[Int]`. However, if you need to return `[Int]` for some reason, you can modify the function like so:

```
sumByStudio3 studioName xs = flip (:) [] $ foldr(\(_,_,z) acc -> z + acc) 0 $ filter (\(_,y,_) -> y == studioName) xs
```

To answer your second question, about summing up all sales, you could do something like this:

```
sumAll :: [Games] -> Int
sumAll [] = 0
sumAll xs = foldr(\(_,_,z) acc -> z + acc) 0 xs
```

Comment: Thank you, nicely explained. Great help.

Comment: So foldl basically reduces the list?

Comment: Yes, `foldl` and `foldr` both reduce a list with some specifed operation, which is summation in this case. Check out this for more on the topic: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold

Comment: It is an accumulator. As the fold acts on each element in the list we use `acc` to keep track of the latest value of the reduction operation. And you can certainly use a more meaningful name for both. The idea behind `(_,_,z)` was to introduce pattern matching.

Comment: oh okay like `count`, sorry I am new to Haskell. Yes thank you I have been learning about pattern matching also.

Answer (score 3):

First pass for me:

```
fst3 (x, _, _) = x
snd3 (_, y, _) = y
thrd (_, _, z) = z
studioSales studio = sum . map thrd . filter ((studio ==) . snd3)
```

I really think your code could do with some better naming, though

```
data Game = Game { title :: String, studio :: String, cntSold :: Int }
type Games = [Game]

test =
    [ Game "Minecraft" "mojang"   100
    , Game "GTA V"     "rockstar" 500
    , Game "Portal"    "valve"    200
    , Game "GTA IV"    "rockstar" 100
    ]

sumSold :: Games -> Int
sumSold = sum . map cntSold

singleStudio :: String -> Games -> Games
singleStudio s = filter ((s ==) . studio)

sumSoldByStudio = (sumSold .) . singleStudio
-- or: sumSoldByStudio s = sumSold . singleStudio s
```

BTW, if you really want a `[Int]` (list of `Int`s) instead of a single `Int`, you can either use `(:[])` or `return` to make a single value into a list (the second one due to list monad).  Like so:

```
sumSold :: Games -> [Int]
sumSold = return . sum . map cntSold
```

Comment: Nice. In the first version, `studioSales` should take `s`, not `studio` as parameter.

Comment: @chi Fixed, differently.